# Predicting occurrence of an event using time series data

Tags: predictive-models, prediction

I have data coming from sensors for 1 month. The data is time series with each data point separated by interval of 1 second. There are predictors like temperature, pressure, speed of the fan that has been recorded by these sensors.
Basis these values the event is recorded. So if the engine is functioning normally then event=0 else the event=1 and this event continues for considerable amount of time say next 10 mins and again gets back to normal.

I am trying to predict the occurrence of the next event basis the values of the predictors. I tried Cox proportional hazard model, however the survival curves are not accurate. Tried random forest too, however the model results were not great. The model accuracy was always at 100%.

Can survival analysis be used on time series data?
Would Clustering help to solve the prediction problem.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean that the models were "not accurate" or "not great"? 100% accuracy seems pretty good to me. In general, it is going to be hard for us to say much here without more information.

Comment: 100% looks like over fitted model.

Comment: if you have a bunch of data from sensors that are specifically built for detecting all the relevant data regarding fan failure, than getting 100% accuracy over 1 month really might not be *that* bad of an over fit (it is very easy to imagine the true sensitivity and specificity are close to 99.99%). But as @gung says, we can't add much given the information provided.